# UISlider subclass : CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uislider, cgcontext

I want to make a UISlider without a track.
Here is the code of my subclass :

```
import UIKit

class topSlider: UISlider {
    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var result = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
        result.size.height = 0
        return result
    }
}
```

I am getting this strange error and the system keeps killing my app due to a memory issue.

> CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   Error: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   clip: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   clip: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>  CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>   Error: CGContextDrawLinearGradient: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

I am using xCode 8.2.1.
Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what happens with `result.size.height = 1`?

Comment: then I think you need to find another way to hide the track, because it doesn't like drawing it with zero height!

Comment: Setting it to 0.01 solves the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to hide the track, just set it to clear color:

```
slider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.clear
slider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.clear
```